# jdk won't install on Intel Atom

Tags: java

I'm trying to install Oracle jdk 17 on my netbook but with no success.
The installer says that the processor (Intel Atom Z3735F) is not supported.

On my desktop Intel i5 the same package is working fine.
I need Java on the netbook to bring at school.

Edit:
The netbook is running on Win 10 Home 32bit on Atom 64 bit processor.

Comment: Is that a 32bit processor per chance?

Comment: @Boris, it's 64bit, and you could easily have checked.

Comment: Can you try another JDK like [Eclipse Adoptium](https://adoptium.net)? Does it result in the same problem?

Comment: The Intel Atom CPU you mentioned is very, very old. It will be very unlikely that you can find a recent Java distribution to support your CPU. You have three choices: Build Java on your own (yes, it is Open Source), use an older version of Java with support for your CPU, or get a new Notebook. The first solution is very complicated if you are not familiar with the process. The second one might not work if your school requires a recent version. The third one is the easiest but you have to spend some money.

Comment: It's probably because that processor lack certain operands which the jdk was built against. If it's running Linux, then look at the output of lscpu, specifically flags. There will be something missing there that the jdk depends on. FWIW, mine has 100 flags, yours will be substantially smaller given that the cpu was launched in 2014 and an Atom.

Comment: @Bib so you're agreeing with the error message saying the processor is not supported.

Comment: @matt yes, the op stated that the installer said that the processor is not supported. It if was a 32/64bit o/s issue, the installer would have said. But then again, I could be wrong...

Comment: Since you're running a 32bit OS you'll need to use a 32 bit jdk. You should be able to use the "https://adoptium.net/releases.html?variant=openjdk11" windows x86 version?

Comment: Oracle only appears to be releasing 64bit versions of the jdk, you could even try java 17 from adoptium, but you need to use the 32 bit (x86 architecture) versions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I did a fast research I found out that the CPU (processor) you're rocking on your netbook is quite outdated today - it's from 2014 ([check Intel Atom Z3735F on the official website](https://ark.intel.com/content/www/us/en/ark/products/80274/intel-atom-processor-z3735f-2m-cache-up-to-1-83-ghz.html)). But it surprisingly should not be the issue (well, it might be - some instructions might be outdated, but I don't think that's the problem), because it actually is 64-bit CPU (it support 64-bit instruction set and it can address more memory - thanks to the wider address bus, OS has to support this as well). Since the new Java JDK 17 LTS is for x64 (64-bit) systems only, and you said that the installer reports that it's not supported on your device. I think that you're not using 64-bit operating system (OS). Do you think this could be the issue? You could easily find out by just easily looking at the task manager to see how much  GB (gigabytes) of RAM you got. If it's 4 GB or less, then it's quite obvious thing. To make yourself sure, just type out `systeminfo` command to the CMD (if you are on Windows) and there under System Type record you will see what type you got (x86-based PC or x64-based PC).

*Edit*: If you are looking for the latest JDK release by Oracle that supports 32-bit systems, then JDK 13 would probably be the best go for you. If you don't need the features introduced in these newer releases, then I would recommend Java JDK 11 LTS, because it's going to be supported until September 2026. And as mentioned by matt in the answer, there is also JDK 17 LTS for x86 systems (32-bit) by Adoptium. Well, or reinstall the 64-bit OS, but that is probably the hardest option.

Comment: Well, your edit matches with my answer.

Comment: > I think that you're not using 64-bit operating system (OS).
Yes, the netbook is on Win10 32Bit.
So this is the issue?
Do you think I can solve the problem reinstalling windows?

Comment: Oracles wndows jdk 17 is 64 bit only. Adoptium has 32 bit versions of jdk 17.

Comment: @Student you would need to install a 64bit version of windows. It appears to be compatible with your processor. It probably won't give you much benefit because I doubt you have more than 4 gigs of ram. So using a 32bit jdk is going to be a bit simpler to test.

Comment: @Nogard about your edit, why JDK 13 specifically when JDK 17 is the latest LTS and the Adoptium builds support 32-bits systems?

Answer (score 1):

Thank you all for pointing me to the right direction.
The issue was caused by the 32bit Os
As suggested by @matt , I installed Adoptium JDK17 x86 that solved my problem.

Comment: In [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69506601/10819573), Nogard has already mentioned: *I think that you're not using 64-bit operating system (OS).* You should consider accepting that answer by clicking the tick mark to the left of the answer.